# Ruby to_xml change attributes name for Api request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I want to convert the keys for xml response So that they match with third party Api request.

```
    class Person1
      include ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml

      attr_accessor :name, :age

      def attributes
        {'name' => nil, 'age' => nil}
      end

      def capitalized_name
        name.capitalize
      end
    end
p = Person1.new
p.name = "test"
puts p.to_xml
```

### output ::-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <person1>
      <age nil="true"/>
      <name>test</name>
    </person1>
```

**I am looking for a way to change keys in xml output like.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person1>
      <Age nil="true"/>
      <Name>test</Name>
</person1>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
puts p.to_xml(:camelize => true)


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Person1>
  <Age nil="true"/>
  <Name>test</Name>
</Person1>
```

Or if the uppercase `Person` bothers you, I guess you can do something like that:

```
puts p.to_xml(:camelize => true).sub('<Person1>','<person1>').sub('</Person1>','</person1>')

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person1>
  <Age nil="true"/>
  <Name>test</Name>
</person1>
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Roko.
Do u know where this option is documented ?

Comment: @sanjee http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_xml
If answer suits your needs, please mark it as correct, ty

Comment: Do u know the other way around like 
object.from_xml(response, :snake_case => true )

Comment: @sanjee Not that I can think of- why? what is it that's missing?

Comment: I need it because I have an object with attributes in snake_case. The response that i received from external api is again in Camelcase . So in order to populate object with values i recevied from external API., ty.